# SQLite does not support this migration operation ('DropForeignKeyOperation')

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I'm building a web API using Asp.Net core 3.0 with EFcore. I'm using code first approach.
I did my initial migration with this model

```
  public class Group {
    [Key]
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Title { get; set; }
   }
```

Later I added a foreign key relationship to this model

```
  public class Group {
    [Key]
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
   }
```

The new migrations generates properly when I run `Add-Migration <migrationName>` on `PMC`. But when I run `update-database` I get this error: SQLite does not support this migration operation ('DropForeignKeyOperation')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/limitations#migrations-limitations) limitation of the SQLite Database Provider:

**Workaround (Source: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/limitations#migrations-limitations-workaround))**

> You can workaround some of these limitations by manually writing code in your migrations to perform a table rebuild. A table rebuild involves renaming the existing table, creating a new table, copying data to the new table, and dropping the old table. You will need to use the Sql(string) method to perform some of these steps.

**Edit**: As directed by @Shawn it seems MSDN is out of date and this is a malpractice.  Instead use the `Sql(string)` method to issue an `ALTER TABLE` statement as documented [here](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html).

Comment: Following that suggested work flow will likely break things quite badly. See https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html for the official steps for making changes `ALTER TABLE` can't.